# Parsing file into MySQL database. String index out of range

Tags: python, mysql

i was inserting data into table in the database , but when i run the python code i am getting the following error.This is the code i have been using to insert data , hope this will help finding a solution'like_so_'

```
vagrant@itmd521:/vagrant$ python 1.py
starting data to insert
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 38, in <module>
    qcode5=line[106]
IndexError: string index out of range
vagrant@itmd521:/vagrant$
```

>

```
import MySQLdb as my
db=my.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="root",passwd="itmd521",db="itmd521")
cursor=db.cursor()
f=open("1997.txt","r")
myList=[]
print("starting data to insert")
for line in f:
    nomention=line[0:4]
    weathstat=line[4:10]
    WBAN=line[10:15]
    obvrate=line[15:23]
    obvhour=line[23:27]
    notknown=line[27]
    latitude=line[28:34]
    longitude=line[34:41]
    FM=line[41:46]
    elevate=line[46:51]
    plac1=line[51:56]
    plac2=line[56:60]
    wdist=line[60:63]
    qdist=line[63]
    phold=line[64]
    phold2=line[65:69]
    phold3=line[69]
    phold4=line[70]
    sk=line[70:75]
    qcode1=line[76]
    phold5=line[77]
    vdist=line[78:84]
    qcode2=line[84]
    phold6=line[85]
    phold7=line[86]
    temperate=line[87:92]
    qcode3=line[92]
    dpoint=line[93:98]
    qcode4=line[99]
    apoint=line[99:104]
    qcode5=line[105]
    sql="insert into record VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" % \
(nomention,weathstat,WBAN,obvrate,obvhour,notknown,latitude,longitude,FM,elevate,plac1,plac2,wdist,qdist,phold,phold2,phold3,phold4,
sk,qcode1,phold5,vdist,qcode2,phold6,phold7,temperate,qcode3,dpoint,qcode4,apoint,qcode5)
    number_of_rows=cursor.execute(sql)
db.commit()
f.close()
db.close()
print("insertion in progress and done")
```

Comment: hi , can you tell me where i am going wrong this is my code, I am new to this ,could please ellaborate,

Comment: Post the block of code that is generating this message and we can help you further. All we can know so far is that you're accessing an invalid array element.

Comment: You should post the file content as well as your expectedly output

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted did not produce the error you posted.  In any case, here is an example of what is happening:

```
line = "hello"
print(line[4])  //=>"o"
print(line[5])  //=> error
```

Here is the way things are:

```
index: 012345
       ||||||
       VVVVV|
       hello|
            |
            V
         nothing there
```

Similarly, the error you posted says that the line in your code:

```
qcode5=line[106]
```

is trying to access a character in the string that is beyond the last character.  However, your code doesn't contain that line of code, so the error was not produced by the code you posted.

Comment: so what should be done? if there is no error in the code

Comment: @SanjitiChakraborty, Well, the idea is to run some code, then post the output of the code you ran.  It sounds like you have several versions of your program and you are mixing up which version you are running.  But you can't index beyond the end of a string, so you ask what is to be done?  Don't index beyond the end of the string.